# SVN repository - have lost some \db\rev files so want to swap in some files from backup - does not work

Tags: svn, repository, corruption

Had an unfortunate development on my SVN repository (1.4.2) - 7 changesets (files in \db\rev) have disappeared.  The reposisitory has around 21,000 check-ins in total.

I have found a SVN Dump file that was produced a few years ago, and luckily it does include all the missing revisions (the dump has around 17000 check-ins starting at 0).

My intention was to create a separate SVN repo, load in all the data from the dump and use this to move the 7 missing rev files back across to the main SVN repository location.

I imported the dump file into its own repo, and checked the content of the \db\revs files.  They contained slight (binary) differences!  As such I wasn't able to simply move the regenerated rev files across to the main SVN repository (I tried this but svn verify failed due to various errors such as file length and malformed headers).

I don't understand why the dump file has produced rev files in different format - I used the same SVN version (1.4.2) and same OS environment.

Is there any other way I can make use of the dump file to recreate the necessary data that my main SVN repo is missing?  I've really like to avoid having to do some major (and risky) repository regeneration from scratch.

Comment: Did the files get deleted from the repository as a normal file delete, or are they gone from all revisions as well?

Answer (score 0):

this sounds indeed strange. I would suggest you try to dump the revisions from 17000 to 21000 from your broken repository (use the **--incremental** option!) and load it into the old repository.